# Storing uniqueidentifier into php variable then inserting variable as uniqueidentifier

Tags: php, sql

I have two different SQL Tables, both of them have an uniqueidentifier field called ID.

On my website, im calling a query to store into a variable the uniqueidentifier field from the table A.

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE Name='{$name}'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    $ID= $row['ID'];
}
```

Then, after storing this unique identifier into $ID, im inserting it into the TableB.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].TableB(ID) values ('{$ID}')";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
```

This will not work, showing the following error on sqlsrv_errors()

***Syntax error, permission violation or other non-specific error.***

The query works properly when we change *$ID* for *newid()*, but im looking towards inserting my own value rather than generating a new one.

The $ID echo shows this: **D52A7C05-0399-4C82-8662-0F5731B4062C,** which is exactly the same value that is currently stored into the TableA id.

Maybe when I am storing the uniqueidentifier on $ID its being converted into string, therefore not being a correct value to be inserted as uniqueidentifier?

**FIXED**: Found out that I had a very small syntax error on the query. Used `var_dump($query);` to figure it. Thanks @ADyson.

Comment: "will not work" means what exactly? What precisely goes wrong? The PHP variable is not populated? The query fails somehow? Something else? Please be specific about your problem. If you can't be any more specific then please do some proper debugging first. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The $ID variable is properly stored with the uniqueidentifier since I can echo it showing the correct value. The problem is that the INSERT query is failing. It works when i use newid() instead of the {'$ID'} but I need to store the $ID value on it rather than generating a new one

Comment: Failing with what error?

Comment: "I can echo it showing the correct value." ...and what _precisely_ does it look like when echoed? Can you show an example please? And your query is failing...but again: failing with what error, _precisely_? It's much easier to help you if you give all the details up front. We can't necessarily guess correctly what error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. The sqlsrv_errors() function shows up "Syntax error, permission violation or other non-specific error.". The uniqueidentifier stored in the database is "D52A7C05-0399-4C82-8662-0F5731B4062C" and thats exactly how it looks when echoed

Comment: You know, as a first step you would be better to use parameterised queries, then you might avoid any issues with escaping values, or other possible syntax difficulties. I'm not saying it will definitely solve this issue, but it's a best practice that you should be following in any case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also have you tried `var_dump($query);` to check the final SQL looks right?

Comment: Or, looking at it again, here's another idea: `INSERT INTO [dbo].TableB(ID) SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE Name='{$name}'` ...I don't think you even need two separate queries here

Comment: Make sure your field types are identical

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. Finally I found out that I had a very small error on the real query syntax (its a way longer query than the posted one) that was ruinning it all. Thanks @ADyson for reminding me to use var_dump($query);